# Issue deleting Google Shared Contact

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-shared-contacts

I've been able to successfully add a contact via the API but I can't delete contacts that I've created.

https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/shared-contacts

```
function deletecontact()
{
  SharedContactsApp.setOAuth2AccessToken(getSharedContactsService().getAccessToken    ());
  var contacts = SharedContactsApp.getContactById('5c8b05ab8c9f68c6');
  SharedContactsApp.deleteContact('5c8b05ab8c9f68c6');
 }
```

I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method "getElements" of undefined. (line 200, file "Code", project "SharedContactsApp")
```

How to remove this error?

Additionally...

I've tried to set a Job Title using the code below but get the following error:

ReferenceError:"profile" is not defined. (line 142, file "Code")

```
function changeJobTitle2() 
{
   SharedContactsApp.setOAuth2AccessToken(getSharedContactsService().getAccessToken    ());
  var contact = SharedContactsApp.getContactById('82f05968956d66f');
  profile.setJobTitle('Google Apps Expert');
}
```

Comment: I ran the tinyTest that Peter Herrmann mentioned in another post and it came back true.

Comment: function hailmary() 
{
 SharedContactsApp.setOAuth2AccessToken(getSharedContactsService().getAccessToken());
  var contact = SharedContactsApp.getContactById('82f05968956d66f');
  SharedContactsApp.deleteContact(contact)
}

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
function hailmary() 
{
  SharedContactsApp.setOAuth2AccessToken(getSharedContactsService().getAccessToken());
  var contact = SharedContactsApp.getContactById('82f05968956d66f');
  SharedContactsApp.deleteContact(contact)
}
```